# Turning off true black pixels (#000000) for LCD?

Tags: battery, screen, screen-brightness, super-amoled

Is there a way to turn off black pixels on LCD screens, similar to how AMOLED devices turn off these pixels?

I've tried those pixel-turn-off apps, but they turn off all pixels within a certain grid, while I wanted just the black pixels to be off.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMOLEDs power the pixels individually; LCDs use a single backlight source to illuminate all pixels from behind. Only until recently that some manufacturers are beginning to implement more granular LCD backlight sources (multiple blocks of light source that illuminates a chunk of pixels each).

What you want to achieve is simply not what LCD is designed for.